# update elasticcache record without totally replacing it

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-ruby

I'm using this to add a bunch of records to the elasticcache index:

```
  def self.index_trends(trend_hashes)
    formatted_trends = trend_hashes.map do |trend_hash|
      {
        index: {
          _index: 'trends',
          _type: 'trend',
          _id: trend_hash["id"],
          data: trend_hash
        }
      }
    end
    elasticsearch.bulk({
      body: formatted_trends
    })
  end
```

Now I need to update a record (given its id). I want to just add one key-val to the `data` hash, not replace the whole state. How can I do this using `elasticsearch-ruby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to do this with ruby, but in ES there is [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html).

Which look like this

```
POST test/type1/1/_update
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.new_field = \"value_of_new_field\""
}
```

[From example](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/update.rb) with ruby should be

```
 client.update index: 'myindex', type: 'mytype', id: '1',
     body: { script: 'ctx._source.tags += tag', params: { tag: 'x' } }
```

Comment: Thank you will give it a try